# To put objects from a class into another class's attribute which is a class itself in Python

Tags: python-3.x, class, oop, tkinter

I have a class named Geometricalobjects of which many classes inherit from : Triangle, Circle, Rectangle, Square,Parallelepiped... 
I also have a Drawmpaper class which has exactly two attributes : its name and a list of geometrical objects. The idea here is to put geometrical objects on a draw paper. (For example, if d=Drawpaper("one") and s=Square(0,1,3) and we do d.addgeometricalobjet(s) it'll add the square whose center is (0,1) and side=3 in a list).
And I want to use a class Display which will inherit from Canvas' class of Tkinter's module in order to take a Drawpaper and display which geometrical objets it's made of.

The problem is that I don't know how to add objects from a class in a class's attribute which itself is a class.
I tried this :

```
class Display(Canvas):
def __init__(self,parent, w, h, bg, draw):
    Canvas.__init__(self, width = w, height = h, bg = bg)
    self.__drawings=drawpaper #drawpaper is actually an object of Drawpaper class
    self.__geometricalobjects=draw._Drawpaper__list_of_geometricalobjects
```

I don't know if this code is correct or it's what's going to resolve my problem.

I hope you can help me to understand those difficult concepts.

Thank you by advance.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, have a look at this page explaining the concept of class inheritance and the  [super() in Python](https://realpython.com/python-super/). This can be quite useful and can already be applied in your code snippet

Regarding your question:

> The problem is that I don't know how to add objects from a class in a class's attribute which itself is a class.

I'm not sure I fully understand your problem, but I can clear some points around:

1. Once you define a class, this is the blueprint of the Python object. When you call that blueprint with the `__init__` method (e.g. `a = Square(0,1,3)`) you are now dealing with an instance of that class, that is stored in the variable `a`
2. Each class can have as many methods and attribute as you want, and will inherit them from the Superclass as well. Those are stored within the assigned variable and can be called from anywhere. The link I gave you has some nice examples, but let's say that:

```
class Square():
    def __init__(self, center_x, center_y, width):
        self.center = (center_x, center_y)
        self.width = width
        self.length = width

 a = Square(0,1,3)
 a.center #will return (0,1)
 a.width #will return 3
```

in your code snippet, if `draw` is an instance of `Drawpaper`, and this class has the attribute `Drawpaper.__list_of_geometricalobjects`, you can access that attribute of the instance by doing `draw.__list_of_geometricalobjects`. However, it is good practise to check whether this is the case by using the `isinstance()` method, or better the `hasattr()` to check for the attribute directly.

Another thing I notice in your code snippet is that `drawpaper` is not defined within the scope of that class. In other words, should this be included in the `__init__` call as an argument? is this a typo?